# Deleting my own questions

Tags: discussion, area-51

I've been deleting quite a few of my own questions on Area 51 when I realised they weren't good questions. Sometimes they were heavily voted but even so, the question wasn't actually a good one. I've just deleted a question on [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/) which had seven votes, but from the discussion I was seeing under the question, it looked like a bad question (i.e. something which wasn't going to attract experts). I've done this several times now but don't seem to see a hit on the reputation. Just wondering why the reputation doesn't go down along with the deleted question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reputation isn't recalculated when you delete a post.

If you run the reputation report - http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation - you'll see your new correct reputation.

If you want to see the correct value on the site then you'll have to request a recalculation from the team.

Comment: Cheers @Grace - I'm getting worse on you're/your :(

Comment: I don't need it to be recalculated. I worked at it in order to get 1,000 points in order to edit the mistakes etc. in other people's proposals and question, but I can't see anything I want above 1,000 points.